# Visual Studio: ¿Incrementar la version del ensamblado automáticamente?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2013

Siempre que publico una aplicacion tengo que acordarme de incrementar la version del ensamblado **manualmente** en propiedades del proyecto->Aplicacion->Informacion de ensamblado. Me parece algo raro el que Visual Studio no lo tenga incluido.

¿Como puedo automatizar ese proceso para que en cada build me incremente la version del ensamblado? o ¿existe alguna extension/plugin que lo haga?

Comment: estas usando c#?

Comment: Hacerlo para proyectos en c# es bastante sencillo, hacerlo para el resto de lenguajes (C++, VB, etc.) ya no.. tendrás que ir a por algun plugin. Aclara esto último para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Como seria con c# mas facil que con otros lenguajes? No creo que visual studio discrimine tanto a los demas lenguajes que soporta y principalmente VB

Comment: chico yo te digo lo que hay... las quejas a Microsoft ;D Si quieres una solución para todos los tipos de proyectos, tendrás que ir a por un plugin.

Comment: ¿@Einer y cuál es la lógica que usas para incrementar la versión?, recuerda que la información de versión de un ensamblado consta: **Versión principal, Versión secundaria, Número de compilación y Revisión**.

Comment: pudiste solucionarlo, tengo el mismo problema.
Saludos